# keeping User.email unique from Django Admin

Tags: python, django, django-authentication

I am using Django 1.3/Python 2.7.

My application is using django.contrib.auth for User management. For the main user registration I have a form which checks if the 'email' has already been registered. So it makes sure all email fields are unique.

But it happens that some admins use the django admin interface to add users, and end up adding duplicate accounts with the same email.

For this purpose I have created a NewUserCreationForm, where I've duplicated the django.contrib.auth.UserCreationForm and added an 'email' field to it.

```
class NewUserCreationForm(forms.ModelForm):
    """                                                                                                                                                                                                             
    A form that creates a user, with no privileges, from the given username and password.                                                                                                                           
    """
    username = forms.RegexField(label=_("Username"), max_length=30, regex=r'^[\w.@+-]+$',
        help_text = _("Required. 30 characters or fewer. Letters, digits and @/./+/-/_ only."),
        error_messages = {'invalid': _("This value may contain only letters, numbers and @/./+/-/_ characters.")})
    password1 = forms.CharField(label=_("Password"), widget=forms.PasswordInput)
    password2 = forms.CharField(label=_("Password confirmation"), widget=forms.PasswordInput,
        help_text = _("Enter the same password as above, for verification."))
    email = forms.EmailField(label=_("Email"), max_length=75)

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ("username", "email")

    def clean_username(self):
        username = self.cleaned_data["username"]
        try:
            User.objects.get(username=username)
        except User.DoesNotExist:
            return username
        raise forms.ValidationError(_("A user with that username already exists."))

    def clean_password2(self):
        password1 = self.cleaned_data.get("password1", "")
        password2 = self.cleaned_data["password2"]
        if password1 != password2:
            raise forms.ValidationError(_("The two password fields didn't match."))
        return password2

    def save(self, commit=True):
        user = super(NewUserCreationForm, self).save(commit=False)
        user.set_password(self.cleaned_data["password1"])
        user.email = self.email
        if commit:
            user.save()
        return user


class CustomUserAdmin(UserAdmin):
    add_form = NewUserCreationForm


admin.site.unregister(User)
admin.site.register(User, CustomUserAdmin)
```

But this code isn't working. I can see the form rendering, but with no email field, just the Username, password1 and password2 fields.

what is it that I am missing here?

Comment: Kudos for posting the code. Note: you should probably **extend** UserAdmin rather than **fork** it.

Comment: @jpic yes, i thought to extend it first. thats DRY. but again, Django has such horrible documentation (great tuttorials, but horrible as docs), they've just put a single line for UserCreationForm.

Comment: The documentation might not be great, but you can always look at the code itself.

Comment: @ThomasOrozco Yes, indeed. I am fairly new to Django (been around 6 months) and I've recently started reading the code whenever necessary, the code base is amazingly readable for such a huge project. But good documentation is absolutely required, especially for ones new to the ecosystem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are missing ... UserAdmin.add_fieldsets, e.g.:

```
class CustomUserAdmin(UserAdmin):
    add_form = NewUserCreationForm
    add_fieldsets = (
        (None, {
            'classes': ('wide',),
            'fields': ('username', 'password1', 'password2', 'email')}
        ), 
    )
```

Comment: I had just figured it out with help of a colleague and was adding the answer. Anyways, thanks for answering.